# Is there a good way to prevent word wrapping within cells in MS Visual Studio Report Wizard?

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix

I'm putting together a report in MS Visual Studio to deploy to SSRS. I'm having trouble with cell data word wrapping.

The CanGrow property is set to False. WordWrap is turned off globally in MS Visual Studio. Is there any way I can just get cell data to just cut off once it reaches the width of the cell?

In the Description column, you can see the data in the cell word wrapping and then being cut off. I've looked at tons of online resources and anyone with similar (not exact) issues have had to 'cheat the system' so to speak to get this to work.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

[Cell Data word wrapping and cutting off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbjhM.png)

The CanGrow property is set to False. WordWrap is turned off globally in MS Visual Studio. I've tried to set the VerticalAlign to 'Bottom' and decrease the height of the cell. This does make it come out on one line but then the data in the entire row is all misaligned and looks horrible.